# Is ArtifactStagingDirectory always empty with each build in DevOps pipeline

Tags: build, azure-devops, pipeline

We are using Build Pipeline in Azure DevOps to create a Deployment Artifact. Typical steps in such pipeline are:

- Build Solution / Project
- Copy dlls output into `$Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory`
- Publish Artifact from `$Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory`

**I just wonder if I can rely on the fact, that on start of each Build the Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory is empty. Or should I clean the folder as first step to be sure?**

From my experience the folder was always empty, but I am not sure if I can rely on that. Is that something specific to Azure hosted Agent and maybe by using custom Build agents I have to do manual clean-ups of this folder? Maybe some old files from last build could remain there? I did not found this info in documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the main idea of this variable `$Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory` is to be a clean area so you can manage the code you're pushing from your repo. As far as I know, there is no explicit information on documentation talking that this folder is empty at every new build, but there are a few "clues":

1. You can see at the [Microsoft's Build Variables documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) that `Build.StagingDirectory` is always purged before each new build, so you have a fresh start every build.
2. In the documentation above you have a few cases where it explicitly cites that some folders or files are not cleaned on a new build, like the Build.BinariesDirectory variable.
3. I've run a few build and realeases pointing to my Web App on Azure, and I never saw an unwanted file or folder that was not related to my build pipeline.

I hope that helps.

Comment: It's explicitly mentioned in the documentation, per your bullet point #1: **This directory is purged before each new build, so you don't have to clean it up yourself.**

Comment: I was blind and overlooked that point in documentation. Many thanks for your answers. Now we are safe the directory is always clean on Build start.